# Java - What is this asking me to do?

Tags: java

It's as follows:

> [image]

I highlighted the part that I don't understand. What exactly does it mean when it's asking me to make those methods accept only two parameters? It seems like you would need 3, which are the test scores for each respective test?

The code I have so far:

```
public class Student {

private String ID;
private double test1;
private double test2;
private double test3;
private double average;

public Student(String sID, double sTest1, double sTest2, double sTest3, double sAverage)
{
    ID = sID;
    test1 = sTest1;
    test2 = sTest2;
    test3 = sTest3;
    average = sAverage;
}

public Student(String sID)
{
    ID = sID;
}

public void setTestScore(double sTest1, double sTest2, double sTest3)
{

}

public void getTestScore(double sTest1, double sTest2, double sTest3)
{

}

public double calcAverage()
{
    average = (test1 + test2 + test3) / 3;
    return average;
}

public void displayInfo(String ID, double test1, double test2, double test3, double average)
{
    System.out.println("Student ID: " + ID);
    System.out.println("Test 1 Score: " + test1);
    System.out.println("Test 2 Score: " + test2);
    System.out.println("Test 3 Score: " + test3);
    System.out.println("Average test score: " + average);
}
}
```

Any insight as to what it's expecting me to do with the `getTestScore` and `setTestScore` methods would be appreciated.

Edit: Looks like the solution is to just use an array to store the values? I thought that would defeat the purpose of structuring it this way but it seems like as a beginner my options are a bit limited.

Comment: Besides from the already realtive good answers below you really should avoid names like "sTest1","sTest2","sTest3" and so on. Try to use speaking names. What does this parameter actually contain? Don't be afraid of using longer sounding names for your code as it helps understanding what is what and also helps if you have to work on this code at a later point in time again.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I don't know why I still do that sometimes but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: the edit-part should be a comment!

Comment: Yeah that was the intention. I don't think it was necessary to edit my post that much though, especially considering that my original edit provided that context.

Comment: That said, thanks for the responses everyone! Onto tackling new (somewhat related) problems now but definitely made good progress.

Comment: Why not ask your teacher, who set you the assignment?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> What exactly does it mean when it's asking me to make those methods accept only two parameters? It seems like you would need 3, which are the test scores for each respective test?

That would be one way to do it, but they want to do it slightly differently.

They want to have a method that sets the score only for a single test.

That is probably better as it

1. can be adapted easily to a greater number of tests
2. allows to set the scores one-by-one (as you may not even know the other scores yet).

So the "extra" parameter specifies which test you are talking about here.

To set all three scores, you would call this method three times (with different parameters).

Comment: That makes sense! However I am still stumped on the code as I have not learned how to correspond a string (test1, test2, etc) with an int (the test number parameter) yet. In other words, I'm not sure how I can do this part without using an array (maybe?) or a series of if statements and I understand that using those would defeat the purpose of formatting it this way.

Comment: Yes, use an array (those have int "keys") or a Map (can also have int keys, or somehow transform them into a String like "test1" --- but why?)

Answer (score 15):

Setter should have 2 parameters: test number and score

```
public void setTestScore(int testNo, double score) {
  //YOUR HOMEWORK
}
```

Getter should return the score for the test number

```
public double getTestScore(int testNo) {
  return YOUR_HOMEWORK;
}
```

**Your Assignment** in this case is to think of a good data structure to hold the results of a number of tests (currently three) and to retrieve them at a later time.

**Hint:** as others here have already suggested, you might think of a datastructure to *map* key values (your test number) to values (your score). The most basic of these structures being an array where the index is your key (watch out: zero-based!) and score is the value at that index...

**With Arrays**

You could still have some way of initialization to specify how many tests there are to be. Lets for a moment think of `double[] scores = new double[3];` as a member variable in your class. Setting the 3rd test to `score` would be as simple as `scores[2] = score;`. Getting the result of the first test simply is `scores[0];`

Comment: Would storing the data in an array (the only real way I can think of doing it at this point too) defeat the purpose of structuring the method this way? It's still certainly miles easier than adding on to a bunch of if statements though, for the purposes of adding more tests in the future and such, so maybe that really was the intent.

Comment: setting the 3rd test to score, you mean?

Answer (score 11):

The set method shouldn't accept all 3 scores at once. It should accept a single score parameter and a second parameter (int whose value is between 1 to 3) to indicate which test score should be updated.

Similarly the get method should accept the test number (between 1 and 3) and return the corresponding score.

Answer (score 8):

The first method should add a test and a score to a Collection, let's say a `HashMap<Integer, Double>`. Like this:

```
public void addScore(int testId, double score) {
    myTestsMap.put(testId, score);
}
```

The second part should retrieve the score from the map, like this:

```
public double getScoreForTest(int testId) {
    if(myTestsMap.containsKey(testId){
        return myTestsMap.get(testId);
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

`myTestsMap` should be a class field so it's state is kept. Create it in the constructor like that:

```
myTestsMap = new HashMap<Integer, Double>;
```

As for a theoretical background:

the two methods are so-called **getter** and **setter**. It is a good practice to keep your class fields *private* and only allow access through such methods. It allows you to analyze the in-coming and out-going data, among other things.

**Map** is a data structure which maps a set of unique keys to non-unique values. **HashMap** is one of Map's implementations.

Comment: why would testid be a double?

Comment: OP used doubles in his code, but you are right, it may just as well be an Integer :-)

Comment: Looks like good reference for the future, but for now that seems a bit beyond what I've learned. Still appreciate the help though!

Comment: Actually, this is just basic Java :-) If you want to start with good practices right away, try to wrap your head around Java Collections, it helps a lot :-)

Comment: @Kelevandos  I agree with that. Even though I've only dabbled with Java as a hobby, I wish I had learned the Collections stuff early, as it would have saved me a lot on redundant/bad code in my early projects.

Comment: If BaloneyOs is going through a college curriculum (like Computer Science), and is just beginning, they may have not covered more advanced data structures than an array yet.

Answer (score 5):

Another option not mentioned here is to hold your test scores in an `ArrayList`:

```
public class Student {
    private String ID;
    private ArrayList<Double> testScores = new ArrayList<>();

    //CONSTRUCTOR

    public void setTestScore(int testNumber, double score) {
        //YOUR HOMEWORK
    }

    public double getTestScore(int testNumber) {
        //YOUR HOMEWORK
    }
```

Now you can add your test scores and they can be positional based on the index in the list.  Note that `ArrayList` is also 0-based, so you'll have to correct for that.  This approach also gives you the added benefit of being able iterate through test scores and print them out in the correct order.

Answer (score 2):

> What exactly does it mean when it's asking me to make those methods accept only two parameters? It seems like you would need 3, which are the test scores for each respective test?

Try thinking about what the method is supposed to do, rather than how you would go about doing it.
The name of the method is a giveaway - setTestScore.
That would indicate to me, that I want to set the score for a single test.

Now, I would ask myself, what information would I need to change the score for a single test?
I would need something that identifies an individual test. E.g the integer 0 for test 1, integer 1 for test 2 etc.
I would also need the actual test score, so that I can store it.
Now I know that I likely need two parameters, one for the test identifier, and one for the test score.

So now, I need a way to store the test score in a specific place using the identifier.
Given that I have an identifier which is an integer, it should hopefully be clear that I would want to use an array.
The reason I would choose an array is because it accepts an integer, and allows me to access the data at that place in the array.

A section of pseudocode to highlight what I have proposed above:

```
setTestScore ( parameter1 testIdentifier, parameter2 testScore )
ArrayOfTestScores[testIdentifier] = testScore
```

---

Note regarding your second question

> It seems like you would need 3, which are the test scores for each
>   respective test?

If someone sent you the following information in an email,
and asked you to store/update the value for a student's test in an excel sheet:

- no value
- 65.7
- no value

Sure, you can see right away you need to update the student's second test.
But, is there a better way?
How about the person just sends me the test number and the score?

Test 2: 65.7

Seems to be easier, because I have an actual identifier for the test to be updated.
And I also don't need redundant information in the email.

When starting off with programming it can help to try and turn the problem into a real life example which you can hopefully relate to. It could help you understand what makes sense and what doesn't. Eventually, as problems get trickier, you will likely need to learn some formal approaches to problem solving. But for this example, making a simple real life equivalent of what you're doing can help.

Answer (score 2):

The student object should have a `Map<Integer, Double>` field that stores the test number as the key and the score they got on that test as the value.  The set method will `put(testNumber, score)` and the get method will return the test score by `get(testNumber);`

What seems confusing perhaps is the requirement to provide a constructor that sets all fields?  Perhaps you expect the constructor method signature to look just like the setTestScore method?

If you're still in need of help, try to think a second about what the lesson is about.  Are you learning about collections?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would want to have everything object oriented, that would mean that the Test themselves would be their own class.

I think what is expected is that the first value is the number of the test (1 through 3) and the second value is the actual value. So the method signature that you have is wrong. It should just have two paramters. The first being the number and the second being the score.

What happens after the setter is called?

Well... you have to decide on some structure to store that data. It is basically three pairs of data. Like I mentioned before, it would be nice to have a Test class, but a simple data structure should suffice. I will give you a hint about the data structure : it should be key/value based. The key is the id of the Test, and the value is the value of the test. Have a read about java collections to see if there is any kind of data structure that can help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are supposed to create a Map of some kind, with the test ID as a key, and the score as a value.

Your setter would populate the map with the score for the current test ID.

Your getter would retrieve the score in the map, corresponding to the asked test ID.

Answer (score -5):

> What exactly does it mean when it's asking me to make those methods
>   accept only two parameters? It seems like you would need 3, which are
>   the test scores for each respective test?

the method should accept test-id and test-score, and set data to proper attribute,

```
public void setTestScore(int testNumber, double testScore)
{
if(testNumber == 1)
      test1=testScore;
else if(testNumber == 2)
      test2=testScore;
else if(testNumber == 3)
      test3=testScore;
}
```

and get method should take 1 param (testNumber)

```
public double getTestScore(int testNumber){
if(testNumber == 1)
      return test1;
else if(testNumber == 2)
      return test2;
else if(testNumber == 3)
      return test3;
}
```

Comment: @Aron_dc i am aware OP can use arrays for example but i wrote based on the class posted by OP that contains different variables for each result, some educational assignments are related tot what they have been tough, so sometimes they CAN'T use arrays (YET)